# Horizontal scroll on a table in a div (HTML, jQueryMobile)?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to put a horizontal scroll on the following situation to be able to scroll photos(I use jquery mobile and need to run the program on android), any idea ? thanks

```
<div data-role="content" class="List" >
   <table>
    <tr> <td>image1</td> <td>image2</td> <td>image3</td> <td>image4</td> </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling you could use something like this

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/experiments/scrollview/
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html ( Horizontal Scrolling )

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt show the content properly, I mean when u scroll, u see that something are changing out side the div, like background colour. but Im sure I can use this solution one day :)

Comment: The page and the divs both scroll, some have different directions for scrolling

Comment: Links no longer exist; possibly here now: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html